# Python copy files script

Tags: python

I built a script in Python to copy any files from a list of folders to a destination folder already made.

```
source = ['c:/test/source/', ]
destination = 'c:/test/destination/'

def copy(source, destination):

    import os, shutil

    try:
        for folder in source:
            files = os.listdir(folder)

            for file in files:
                current_file = os.path.join(folder, file)
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(folder, file), destination)

    except:
         pass
```

The problem with this script is that it didn't copy the sub folders. Any suggestion to fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)

```
shutil.copytree(os.path.join(folder, file), destination)
```

but `shutil.copytree` won't overwrite if folder exist,
if you want to overwrite all, use [distutils.dir_util.copy_tree](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree)

```
from distutils import dir_util
dir_util.copy_tree(os.path.join(folder, file), destination)
```

Comment: Yes it is almost working, but still another problem. Indeed the script told me that there already is a folder named 'destination'. What I want is to force the copy of folders, files and subfolders if they already exists.

Comment: Yes it overrides all files. But ther is a last issue ! :) The sub folder is not created... And so I have this kind of error : distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not create 'c:/test/destination\Nouveau dossier\Nouveau document texte (2).txt': No such file or directory

Comment: I have to create myself the sub folder to get it work. Any solution ?

Comment: what do you mean the sub folder ? for example if you have folder `name1` and you what to copy the folder `name1` to folder `name2` but you don't have the `name2` folder it will create it, but if you don't have `name1` it will raise `DistutilsFileError` you need to have `name1` folder

Comment: In the source folder, I have files and others folders which contains other files and other folders maybe. So I want to copy everything in a destination folder. However if I have 'c:/test/source/subfolder/file.txt' and if my destination folder exists but is empty, so there is an error.

Comment: can you try simple in a new file.py make `dir_util.copy_tree('c:/test/source', 'c:/test/source1')` give you top file what you need to copy, not all submodules